# Making ajax call in Reactjs, value coming empty while rendering

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js and trying to render the result from an ajax call using react but the data is not coming to the render() function. If you know any other best way to solve this issue or make an ajax call in react then please let mention the link for the same. Need to render data in react from an API.Below is the javascript  for the same. The value is coming in componentDidMount method and result is having the value. But when I try to access in the render, then its empty. I tried to assign value to a global object array but that is also not working. Any solutions for this.The link mentioned in the post for fetching data is a working link. You can call that link in the browser and check for json field.

```
var UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      username: '',
      lastGistUrl: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
      this.setState({
        username = result.description,
          lastGistUrl = result.html_url
      })
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    React.createElement("div", null, this.state.username, " 's last gist's url  is ",
      React.createElement("div", null, this.state.lastGistUrl, ""), ".")

  }
});



ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(UserGist, { source: "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists" }), document.getElementById('container'));
```

[Fiddler link](https://jsfiddle.net/harshitc14/ey18zaef/)

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains syntax errors. Replace `=` with `:`.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
    this.setState({
      username: result.description,
      lastGistUrl: result.html_url
    })
  }.bind(this));
},
```

More errors to come:

- `render` missing return statement. Should be `return React.createElement`
- `result` is an array not an object. You need to somehow handle this. For example pick the first element `result = result[0]`
- `setState` is method. You should call it not make an assignment `setState=({})` should be `setState({})` This one was in demo code.

See fixed [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/ey18zaef/2/).

Comment: Have made changes as you mentioned, but values not coming for rendering. Have added one more line, have a look and revert for further changes. Just check the API link that is being used.

Comment: @HarshitC. Set a breakpoint in success callback. And check if it was called and what was the value of `result`.

Comment: Values is coming in `componentDidMount` method but not in the render method. Array of objects is coming in `componentDidMount` , same should come in render method which is not happening.

Comment: @HarshitC. Could you plz create an example using jsfiddle.net or plncr.co demonstrating the issue? This code should work.

Comment: check the fiddler link in the question. If any issues please revert.

Comment: @HarshitC.Check updated fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/ey18zaef/2/

Comment: Thanks, but i am trying to display the whole list of values ( description and html url) obtained from the API call.

Comment: @HarshitC. " i am trying to display the whole list of values" there is nothing in your code that even looks like an attempt to do it.

Comment: I am facing issue in displayinh the list, how to set the state here for a list of objects. Every time the value of the object will be different and then there is only one state. Tried using for loop but nothing seems to get me proper solution.

Comment: Rule of thumb: One question per question :)